# How to get current select customer id in magento customer page

Tags: magento

As title, how to get current selected customer id in custom customer edit page,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code -

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
     $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
      echo $customerData->getId();
}
```

Hope, It may help!